# which opensouce image library supports most file format can be used in commercial application

Tags: c++, image

which opensouce image library supports most file format can be used in commercial application?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a pretty powerful and widely used set of tools.

Answer (score 3):

[CxImage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cximage/) which can be used under the [zlib license](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_license.html)

> CxImage is a C++ class that can load,
>   save, display, transform images in a
>   very simple and fast way.
>
> CxImage is open source and licensed
>   under the zlib license. In a nutshell,
>   this means that you can use the code
>   however you wish, as long as you don't
>   claim it as your own.
>
> With more than 200 functions, and with
>   comprehensive working demos, CxImage
>   offers all the tools to build simple
>   image processing applications on a
>   fast learning curve. Supported file
>   formats are: BMP, GIF, ICO, CUR, JBG,
>   JPG, JPC, JP2, PCX, PGX, PNG, PNM,
>   RAS, SKA, TGA, TIF, WBMP, WMF, RAW,
>   CRW, NEF, CR2, DNG, ORF, ARW, ERF,
>   3FR, DCR, X3F, MEF, RAF, MRW, PEF,
>   SR2.
>
> Cximage is highly portable and has
>   been tested with Visual C++ 6 / 2008,
>   C++ Builder 3 / 6, MinGW on Windows,
>   and with gcc 3.3.2 on Linux. The
>   library can be linked statically, or
>   through a DLL or an activex component.